# Data not populating into view

Tags: angularjs, state

I am using state provider to route ,when i switch between pages sometimes data loads on view sometimes it's not ,though i can successfully get data from my db but it's not population in my view file to populate the data I need to refresh the page every time

Answer (score 0):

When you switch page, components that were shown previously get disposed. 
So any propriety of the scope or any propriety of the previous components gets desroyed.

The simplest solution is refetch needed data in the component(s) that you are showing in the "next" page, best practice is to do that in $oninit function.

Another option is to build a service that stores data between routes and components. This solution is more complicated.

Comment: I am re fetching data its showing on console even but not populating in view,even i am storing some of the data into local storage as well that also not showing on view when i switch from one page to another if i hard refresh the page then it start showing

Comment: Strange, something isn't working with component's template, but without other information i cannot make any deeper supposes. It seems that you do different things when you swithch to and when you load that page, focus on that differences.

Comment: is it because my controller files taking time to fetch data form db and view get load before  data get fetched successfully from db ?. i am using angularjs and for routing i am using ui.route

Comment: It souldnt, views get revalued at any model change.
Where are you storing your values and how are you showing them?

Comment: i fetching all data from dynamodb and storing it in my controller files .
ex $scope.productList=data from dynamodb) and try to show $productList in my view file, $scope.productList do get value every time but its not rendering in view file if i switch from one page to another some time it does some time its not

Comment: Try to fetch data in oninit function, then store it in a controller propriety then access those prorpieties from view using $crtl.someProp, and see what happens.
Maybe $scope isn't working as it should.